# Initialise an element with a function dynamically - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-router

I'm currently using react router to build my site, but I have `.dropdown`s on several pages which I initialise using `$('.dropdown').dropdown();`

How can I keep initialising my dropdowns on every page I visit using react router? The `onhashchange` doesn't seem to register the URL changing.

This is what my *dropdown* function looks like.

**jQuery**

```
    $(function() {
        $('.dropdown').dropdown();
        $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
            $('.dropdown').dropdown();
        });
    });

    $.fn.extend({
        dropdown: function(o){
            var o = $.extend({ maxHeight: 600, buffer: 100, delay: 500 }, o);

            return this.each(function(){
                var dropdown = $(this),
                    toggle = dropdown.find('.toggle'),
                    menu = dropdown.find('.menu'),
                    a = dropdown.find('a'),
                    liheight = dropdown.height();
                if(!dropdown.length){ return; }


                toggle.click(function(e){
                    if(!menu.is(':visible')) {
                        $('.menu').parent().removeClass('open');
                    }
                    menu.parent().addClass('open');
                });

                $(document).bind('click', function(e){
                    if (! $(e.target).parents().hasClass('dropdown'))
                        menu.parent().removeClass('open');
                 });
            });
        }
    });
```

I have also tried this, but still no luck:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.dropdown' function(e){
  $('.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

**Edit: The solution**

Used the `componentDidMount()` function in react router to initialise the dropdown every time the dropdown was rendered. This is what I added:

```
export const elDropdown = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown').dropdown();
        })
    },
    render() {
        return(
            <div>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialise the dropdowns after they become available on the page. The right place to do that is in React's lifecycle methods. In that case, `componentDidMount` - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

You can create a component that wraps the dropdown and initialises it. Here is a simple example of how you could achieve that:

```
class DropdownWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.id = 'someUniqueID'
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    $('#' + this.id).dropdown();
  }
  render(){
    return <select id={this.id} otherProps={this.otherProps} ></select>
  }
}
```

Notice that you  will need to use unique identifiers. You can pass it to the component manually or create it randomly.

Comment: Took `componentDidMount()` into consideration as you mentioned and edited my component a bit, updated my question with the answer. Thanks!